# How to implement 'workers' correctly

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

I created a simple service to allow user convert a string to upper case.

```
def upper_service(s):
    return s.upper()
```

Now, suppose I want only maximum 1000 workers to do my job (corresponding 1000 concurrent users at a time), but I don't want to create all 1000 workers immediately, just create when needed (an user sends a request to server) and max workers is 1000. If more than 1000 concurrent users, other requests will be added to a 'queue' or something like that.

So how can I do that with python? My approach is good enough or can be improved?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
import queue, threading, time, random, datetime, webbrowser, urllib.request

def main():
    n = 1000
    startTime = datetime.datetime.now()
    q = queue.Queue()
    threads = []

    for i in range(0,n):
        t = threading.Thread(target=async_shit, args=(q, i))
        t.daemon = False
        threads.append(t)

    [x.start() for x in threads]
    [x.join() for x in threads]
    ....
```

Comment: IMO, this code creates 1000 threads and do the job immediately. It just serve 1000 users only one time. I want the program can serve every user forever.